# How to separate the rows depending of the column's value witin two tables in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have two tables: `markers` and `markers_types`.

```
markers
id, type_id,    lat,    lng
1   1           42.000  2.500
2   1           41.000  2.400
3   2           40.000  2.300

markers_types
id, name,   image
1   TYPE1   type1.png
2   TYPE2   type2.png
```

How can I retrieve the rows from the DB correctly, so for example, if first row from `markers` have column `type_id` set to `1`, I want to output an image from corresponding ID from the others table `markers_types` where `markers.type_id` is equal to `markers_types.id` ? Sorry for dumb question, but can't get it.

Here is my `map_model.php`:

```
class Map_model extends CI_Model{
    ...
    function get_coordinates(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('markers');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->result() < 1)
            return false;
        else{
            $results = $query->result();
            return $results;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `app/controllers/map.php`:

```
$dbresults = $this->map_model->get_coordinates();

foreach($dbresults as $item){
    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = $item->lat.','.$item->lng;
    $marker['icon'] = base_url().'assets/img/ico/'.$item->image; // <-- I need to output here correct type image
    $marker['infowindow_content'] = $item->description;
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
}
```

How can I mix them, so it will output appropriate image depending on the marker's type ?

I'am complete newbie at MySQL, so pls sorry in advance for that kind of basic question, I tried but didn't succeed to find out the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM markers LEFT JOIN marker_types ON markers.type_id = markers_types.id");

// RETURNS AN ARRAY
$query->result_array();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This cleared out my mind, i thought LEFT JOIN is used at completly something different case. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Actually, I have problem, it merges the columns with the same name into the one ( i mean `id` column), how to separate them ?

Comment: You have to alias them.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978078/alias-a-column-name-on-a-left-join